# how to sendMessage to Qwidget

Tags: c++, qt, sendmessage

I have a compiled program that is based on QT library and have a toolbar that it is a `QWidget`. I want to use [`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) to click on a specific button that is placed in that toolbar (`QWidget`).

If I use `SendMessage()` I need to know handle of button, but when checking handles by softwares like spy++, Winspector Spy,.. they return handle of whole `QWidget` not the button in it!! Why? And how to get that?

Comment: What about finding desired widget object (button) and calling its `QAbstractButton::click()` function directly?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, plain-and-simple. Qt widgets are not Windows-native controls, and in fact most of the modern applications don't use native controls, so `SendMessage` to-a-native-control is an obsolete approach.

Your Qt program could implement some RPC mechanism, e.g. [Qt Remote Objects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtremoteobjects-index.html), or [ØMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all).

You could also catch custom messages sent via `SendMessage` using [native event filters in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractnativeeventfilter.html). You can install the native event filter instance as follows:

```
bool installNativeEventFilter(QAbstractNativeEventFilter *filter) {
  if (auto *dispatcher = QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()) {
    dispatcher->installNativeEventFilter(filter);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: As i in question said  the QT program source is not available and is a compiled program so i can't change that!! if i understood you suggest me to implement event filter in QT yes? if yes how?

Comment: @AliDamirchy There's literally nothing you can do then, other than hardcoding the location of the widget based on the size of the window, and using `SendMessage` to send the mouse click. You'd be sending the message to the entire window, but the location will affect what control is clicked (if any).